# Zend Framework 2 index.php in root folder

Tags: zend-framework2

I am bulding a website with zend framework 2 and a URL typically looks like this:
*domain.com/public/routename/action/params*

In the skeleton application i don't have index.php by default, so i created one what basically includes the index.php from the public folder.(This is absolutely not the correct solution). What works but slows down the whole website, also the redirect plugin still redirects to *domain.com/public/routename/action/params* insetad of *domain.com/routename/action/params*

How could i skip the "public" in the URLs and get the redirect plugin to work?

Comment: Can you not change your document root to point at the public folder instead (which is the correct way to set it up)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your web server so that it serves from `public` instead of the ZF2 root folder.

Not sure if you use IIS or apache or NGiNX, so without those details it is hard to say what you need to do exactly. But it should be easy to find a 'how to' for your particular web server.

It comes down to configuring what folder should be server for that particular virtual host.

[Google can help you](https://www.google.se/search?q=configure+directory+virtual+host)

Answer (score 1):

Either you can do this from webserver from where you can point the public folder index.php so either point the domain to zf2 you should point to zf2/public/index.php

Another way is you can use htaccess and remove the public url